# Performant/simple way of composing multiple fragment shaders in threejs

Tags: three.js

Context: trying to do something like this https://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/webgl/gpu/waves/barkley.html in a three.js texture. It's a simulation. There are two fragment shaders: one does the simulation, one draws it. Vertex shader is involved as well of course, but in a pretty trivial way that just gives the fragment shader a UV coordinate.

The one that draws that takes place in a fragment shader

I've thought about using a canvasTexture or a framebuffer texture. But this isn't great, because I might want to do some post-processing, eg write the "drawing" shader myself.

So here's a "simulation". What it does is, for each point in the simulation (it's a grid) it averages the current value and the value of the pixel to the right of it (untested). The simulation actually involves two textures - you read from texture1, write to texture2, then draw texture2, and then in the next frame you read from texture2, write to texture1, then draw texture1. So the gl_FragColor has to be written to another texture.

```
uniform sampler2D previousFrameSimulationTexture;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
const float d = 1./simulationWidth.;
void main(void)
{
   vec4 t = texture2D(previousFrameSimulationTexture, vTexCoord);
   float r = t.r;

   r += texture2D( uTexSamp, vec2(vTexCoord.x + d, vTexCoord.y) ).r
   gl_FragColor = vec4(r, 0., 0., 0. );
}
```

And here's the "drawing" shader - this is the part that would be at home in a three.js fragment shader.

```
uniform sampler2D currentFrameSimulationTexture;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
void main(void)
{
   vec4 t = texture2D(uTexSamp, vTexCoord);
   gl_FragColor = vec4(t.r, 0., 0., 1.);
}
```

The question is, how do I make sure that currentFrameSimulationTexture makes it into the three.js fragment shader to be postprocessed and drawn onto the texture that we actually see?

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_fire) do something similar? It's code is [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/objects/Fire.js).

Comment: Thank you, but it would appear that this is a bit better: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=oce#webgl_shaders_ocean2